# Show ab is also a unit

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

Given A, a ring with 1, show that if $a,b \in A$ are units, then $ab$ is also a unit.
I proceeded like this:
$aa^{-1}=1$ and $bb^{-1}=1$
then $aa^{-1}=b^{-1}b \rightarrow aa^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1} \rightarrow baa^{-1}b^{-1}=1$.

My problem with this one is that I'm not allowed to use commutativity to reorder the term $ab$ and, is it possible to assume $a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}$? Can you provide me with hints?

Comment: Whe did you use the `proof-verification` tag? Which proof are we supposed to verify?

Comment: Why do you think you need commutivity?

Comment: Since $a$ is a unit, then it has an inverse $a^{-1}$.  The same is true for $b$.  Can you combine these inverses to obtain an inverse for $ab$?

Comment: If you had commutativity what would you have done? Why can't you do that without it?  Can you work around it?

Comment: No.  You can not assume $a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$ because $a*b*a^{-1}*b^{-1} \ne 1$ because you can not transpose the order.  But what if you put the in a *different* order from that beginning?  What *other* order can you arrange $a,b,a^{-1}, $ and $b^{-1}$ so they result in $1$?

Comment: Obscure hint.  If $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ then $ba = k\implies b=baa^{-1} = ka^{-1}\implies 1 = bb^{-1} = ka^{-1}b^{-1}=k(ab)^{-1}\implies ab = 1*ab = k*(ab)^{-1}(ab) = k*1 = k$.  So $ba =ab$.  That means if that were the inverse than that  would prove the group is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find an $x$ so that $abx= 1$

So that means $a(bx) = 1$ so what does $bx = ???$.

Can you go on?

> $ab = ab$
>
>  $ab*b^{-1} = a*1 = a$
>
>  $ab*b^{-1}a^{-1} = a*a^{-1} = 1$
>
>  So $b^{-1}a^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It's the same identity for $(AB)^{-1}$ that works for square matrices.

Comment: More accurately, the square matrices have the same inverse that work on rings with identities.